# Different types of the same object

Tags: iphone, swift, object, subclass

So, I'm in Xcode and programming a small program from a friend.

I want to initialize several instances of an object, put them in an array and then iterate through it (via a function that returns a string). Each object adds some text to that string when it's iterated, depending on the variables of the object.

Let's say the class is Tree. The variables in the class are name (string), height(int) and a hasLeaves(bool)(weather it currently has leaves on it or not). I could easily print:

"This is a *name* that is *height* meters tall and *has leaves*.

**The problem** is that I want the string to be a bit different, depending on which kind of tree it is. Like this:

The oak(*name*) is big and lifeful, it's *height* meters tall and *has leaves*.

Apple trees(*name*) carries some apples, it's *height* meters tall and *has leaves*.

If you ever visit Sweden you should check out the firs(*name*), they are *height* tall and *haven't got leaves*.

I don't want you to write the code for me, but give me a clue. I don't know what to look for. I was thinking about creating a subclass for each Tree, but every subclass would only appear once in the program and I don't know if it's necessary or not.

As you recognize, I'm having a hard time even formulating this question, but if you understand my intentions I'm glad for any clue I can get.

**Edit: So this is my attempt to show it in code:**

Class:

```
class tree {

var treeHeight: Int?
var treeWidth: Int?
var hasLeaves: Bool
var treeString: String


init (height: Int?, width: Int?, leaves: Bool, theString: String) {

    self.treeHeight = height
    self.treeWidth = width
    self.hasLeaves = leaves
    self.treeString = theString

    }
```

}

Main function:

```
var oak: tree = tree(height: 1, width: 2, leaves: true, theString:"Oh, the mighty oak")
var appleTree: tree = tree(height: 1, width: 2, leaves: false, theString: "Yummy Apples")

var treeArray: Array = [oak, appleTree]
var resultString = "This is the stories of the trees: "


for tree in treeArray {

        if tree.hasLeaves == true {

            resultString = resultString + tree.theString
            }

        }
```

So, I want the string added to the "resultString" to be different, depending on what kind of tree it is, but I don't want to set that string in the initialization of the object, but rather from what "kind" of tree it is. Does that make it easier to understand?

I want the string (treeString) to be static depending on what "kind" of tree it is. So if it is an oak, the string is always "Oh, the might oak".

Comment: How are you going to “initialize several instances of an object”?  Are you going to hard-code the values?  Read them from a file?  Show us the code you've written so far.

Comment: You'd better elaborate an idea about how to solve this, write some code and post it here, highlighting what you think doesn't work properly - your question, as it is now, it's too generic and it might soon be closed for being off topic

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies. I will post some code soon. To you, Rob, I might use the words wrong, I just started programming some months ago.

Comment: Updated with some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want a tree class with some properties like leaves, etc.  Maybe you also want to subclass leaves with additional properties like color, etc.  I recommend the WWDC 2014 video:

http://youtu.be/W1s9ZjDkSN0

Somewhere around 30 minutes they have a demo of a Car class with RaceCar at subclass.

Regarding creating the objects, you can build each object individually and then collect them in an array as one option.  For example, maybe in a form on your app the user inputs data for a class or subclass and then you create an object, store to a master array which you then archive to a file.

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve, I appreciate the link and the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

So, if anyone stumbles in to this question, this is what I learned:

I was looking for subclasses and protocols. There are methods to determining whether an object is of a certain subclass, and in my case, I could have a protocol called "Tree" with certain methods and/or methods, and then make subclasses to this protocol, called "oak" and "fir".